# How to annotate type argument in Kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, generics, annotations

Essentially, I'm trying to get something like this

```java
public class Post {

  public final @Nullable Optional<@Size(min = 10) String> title;

  public Post(@JsonProperty("title") Optional<String> title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

but in Kotlin.

I've tried

```kotlin
class Post(
  @field:Size(min = 10) val title: Optional<String>?
)
```

but that annotates the title property and not the String inside the Optional.

Is there a way to achieve this in Kotlin?

The context of this is to use validators in Spring Boot to validate the given string, if it is present. The Optional is there to allow me to distinguish between the user sending

```json
{
    "title": null
}
```

or

```json
{}
```

Comment: The annotation goes in the same place as in Java without any target qualifier: `val title: Optional<@Size(min = 10) String>?`

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you have any idea why Spring Boot, even with your suggestion, isn't validating the input at all?

Comment: Sorry, don't use Spring.